# What is the Probability of the Outcomes of a "Repeat Until Success" Experiment?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have an procedure that is known to be a Bernoulli trial with two possible outcomes. Let the probability of the outcome labeled success be $p$. If the experiment is to repeat the procedure until a successful outcome is acquired, what is the probability of the different outcomes (all of which are described by $n$ fails followed by $1$ success)?

Comment: Is this not a geometric distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that. Post an answer with a link to a page describing the geometric distribution and receive your reward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities are given by the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution):
$$\mathsf P(n\text{ failures before success})=(1-p)^np$$